# How common is the ejection of small objects during final stage separation?

Tags: debris, stage-separation

> [image]
> Source: Crew-2 launch; [YouTube](https://youtu.be/lW07SN3YoLI?t=16871) (timestamp link)

That object seen moving right to left is the reason I ask. By playing the video frame-by-frame, it *seems* like it's a small object close to the camera inside the second stage, and it *looks* like a spinning flat spacer.

How common is the release of such objects? I'm asking out of curiosity since tiny untrackable objects could pose threats I'd imagine.

---

*I initially asked about Dragon 2, but now realizing information may not be as public as for say NASA's own vehicles, I've made the question applicable to similar launches.*

Comment: Haven't yet seen a stage separation (of ANY stage, of ANY vehicle) that did not sputter bits n pieces of stuff all over the place. These objects are in Low orbit(or very often not quite in orbit), and have huge surface-to-mass ratios, thus will reenter relatively quickly.